# Syberia not running under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, gaming, 3d

I want to run an old game named Syberia on a Windows 7 PC. But whatever I do I get the Error

```
No 3D accelerator available:
either your graphic card does not reach the requirements for that Game or an error has happened which requires the reboot of your computer.
```

- Windows 7 64 bit
- AMD FX 4100 Quad Core
- AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series

All drivers are up to date. Running in compatibility modes for 98, 2000, and XP has no effect. Setting to 8 bit colors does not help, but it reduces the error message to `3D mode could not initialized`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never had much luck getting it to work and had to resort to buying the game again from Good Old Games (link omitted so it doesn't look like advertising).  I think Steam may also sell Syberia and Syberia 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure your graphics drivers are updated.
2. Install game in XP compatibility mode and run in same mode.
3. Try running game as admin.
4. Install all game patches.
5. Try reducing your resolution to as low as 800x600 if possible.
6. If you own the game try a NoCD patch.
7. If all else fails a VM might be the only solution.